# async function not triggering on onpress of touchableopacity

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have the following function

```
 const onStartRecord = async () => {
    console.log("record");
    const path = "hello.m4a";
    const audioSet = {
      AudioEncoderAndroid: AudioEncoderAndroidType.AAC,
      AudioSourceAndroid: AudioSourceAndroidType.MIC,
      AVEncoderAudioQualityKeyIOS: AVEncoderAudioQualityIOSType.high,
      AVNumberOfChannelsKeyIOS: 2,
      AVFormatIDKeyIOS: AVEncodingOption.aac,
    };
    console.log("audioSet", audioSet);
    const uri = await audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder(path, audioSet);
    audioRecorderPlayer.addRecordBackListener((e) => {
      setRecordSecs(e.current_position);
      setRecordTime(audioRecorderPlayer.mmss(Math.floor(e.current_position)));
    });
    console.log(`uri: ${uri}`);
  };
```

inside touchableOpacity when I call the function like so

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onStartRecord()}>
```

it is not triggering, if I remove the callback and write the function as follows

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={onStartRecord()}>
```

I am getting error as

```
Exception in Native call from JS
```

could anyone please help me out here as to what should I do in order to call the function?

Comment: [TouchableOpacity](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity): The right way to call a function would be: `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onStartRecord()}>` or `<TouchableOpacity onPress={onStartRecord}>`

Comment: @AjeetShah have already mentioned the error which I get when I remove the callback.

Comment: Is the onStartRecord Function even working? Did you try to call it from somewhere else to see if it brings back some result?

Comment: As Ajeet said you need to do `<TouchableOpacity onPress={onStartRecord}>`. Note the lack of `()`

Comment: @SurajRao with () at the end it will anyway not trigger and without adding the callback I am getting Exception in Native call from JS, have mentioned in my question

Comment: Can you edit your question and share the whole code with the issue debugged, there should be more visibility if you need your issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onStartRecord.bind(this)}>
```

Comment: This is a function based component

Answer (score 0):

you should use this format for call function. I try that's work:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>{ this.onStartRecord()}}>
```